Can’t get Distcc to work
I've followed the steps on gentoo wiki (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc) for both host and client but its not distributing the work.
Host is running on 11.0.0.200
Client is running on 11.0.0.201
Installed distcc on both.
Host configuration:
/etc/conf.d/distccd -> DISTCCD_OPTS="--allow 11.0.0.0/24"
rc-update add distccd default
rc-service distccd start
/etc/portage/make.conf -> MAKEOPTS="-j12" FEATURES="parallel-fetch"
Client configuration:
/etc/distcc/hosts -> localhost 11.0.0.200
/etc/portage/make.conf -> MAKEOPTS="-j29 -l2" FEATURES="parallel-fetch distcc"
~/.bashrc -> export PATH="/usr/lib/distcc/bin:${PATH}"
Neither make nor portage on the client is distributing any work to the host.
What am I missing here?

are distccd servers started on the build host(s)? can communication be established, or is there a firewall in the way? I'm not aware of a DISTCCD_OPTS environment variable, and man distccd doesn't mention it? the gentoo page on distcc might be outdated or wrong.

(also note that I found sccache to be the superior combined build artifact cacher and workload distributor, because it can package the compiler and libraries you need to build on the other machines, so that not all machines have to have all identical environments)

Yes, the distcc processes are are running on both machines. There’s no firewall in between. The DISTCCD_OPTS is an instruction on the Gentoo wiki, but the corresponding /etc/conf.d/distccd does include it already by default. So I assume it should be kept, just changed to the corresponding 11.0.0.0/24 range.

I forgot to mention, both machines are running Gentoo musl version. Don’t know if that is a deal breaker in this case or not but thought it would be worth pointing out.

it should generally not make a difference.

Would you want to try wireshark to see whether distcc causes any traffic on either end?

Is 11.0.0.200 your IP Address or the DistCC version? Same with 11.0.0.201?
